# eclipse - how to add more info to tooltip of a variable/object/class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When I place my mouse over a variable like this one `msgProcessedCount++;` the tooltip contains `BYTE msgProcessedCount = 0;`

This is ok but could be better.

**QUESTION**
Is there a way to add more info like:

- file in which it's defined
- class in which it's defined: in a class hierarchy, the variable could be defined in a base-r class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean adding this info just by changing some settings, then no. The functionality you describe would have to be implemented.

That said, you're welcome to [contribute](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing) a patch that implements this.